# How to define special characters in array implementing Java application?

Tags: android, xml

I am implementing input method related application in Android. In this
application I'm using special characters and symbols

```
Array.xml

 <item>a'</item>
```

a' is not reading remaining all numeric and alphabets are reading. How
can implement special symbols reading scenario?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in xml replace this  **'** character '

Some other xml characters

```
1. & - &amp; 
2. < - &lt;
3. > - &gt;
4. " - &quot;
5. ' - &#39;
6. { - &#123;
7. } - &#125;
8. @ - &#64;

ex:   a' Code  =   a&#39; Code
```

see this [link](http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/) for more characters...

**EDIT1 03-12-2013**

Above links seems broken now. Here are some other links

[Link1](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)
[Link2](http://symbolcodes.tlt.psu.edu/accents/codealt.html)
[Link3](http://www.yellowpipe.com/yis/tools/ASCII-HTML-Characters/)
[Link4](http://www.theworldofstuff.com/characters/)
Hope this will help.

Comment: The link that you directed is not working anymore.. Do you know how to define "@" in xml characters?