# Java Split Text to 2 Arrays

Tags: java, android, html, arrays

I have following text:

```
    <option value="{0}">hello1</option>
    <option value="{1}">hello2</option>
    <option value="{2}">hello3</option>
    <option value="{3}">hello4</option>
    <option value="{4}">hello5</option>
    <option value="{5}">hello6</option>
    <option value="{6}">hello7</option>
    <option value="{7}">hello8</option>
```

All above is in one String.

I have 2 Arrays:

```
valueArray;
nameArray;
```

So, any tip on how to get the helloX into nameArray and get all value into valueArray?

//Simon

Comment: You need to use an XMLPullParser, and then parse the option start tag for your value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regex and populate the arrays. Here is a small test program I wrote:

```
public static void main(String [] args) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<option value=\"(.*?)\">(.*?)</option>");
    String line = "<option value=\"{1}\">hello0</option>";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
    while (m.find()) {
        String value = m.group(1);
        String name = m.group(2);
        System.out.println(value);
        System.out.println(name);
        // Now add to your arrays
    }
}
```

I would not use this as a standard method for parsing a complicated xml file. Use an xml parser if this is the case.

Comment: Hmm, m.matches is never true...Any idea?

Comment: Well, your code works but it won't find if I replace line with my string

Comment: Can you provide the actual string that you're trying to parse?

Comment: In that case, use m.find() instead of m.matches(). If there may exist multiple matches per line of text, call m.find() multiple times until it returns false.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10564/discussion-between-nate-and-androidxtr3men)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the position of `>` using `start =str.indexof(">");`

also position of `</` using `stop=str.indexof("</");`

then get string str = str.subString(start,stop);

you will get helloX...

=====================================

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000095/1289716 see this answer.....

replace your **{** bracket and **}** bracket with  **& #123; ** and **& #125;**

Comment: I find this type of solution to be clunky and error prone. It will quickly fail with `<option value="<{0}>">hello0</option>`.