# How to encode a Euro symbol into strings.xml in android XML files

Tags: java, android, xml

I thought, that this is gonna be pretty easy to find out. However, google is giving me just bad results. Please, does anyone know how can I write a Euro symbol into a strings.xml value? I still get an exception that such value is not allowed. Thanks.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/10000095/1289716 

and this link http://tntluoma.com/sidebars/codes/

Answer (score 24):

Use the XML/HTML € entity:

```
&#8364;
```

Comment: All codes here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entities_in_XML - use the Unicode Code Point (decimal) ... it's the "decimal" number in the parenthesis ... e.g., for quote, you can use &#34;