# ksoap2 xmlPullParserException unterminated entity ref

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I have a user email me yesterday that he is having a problem with my application so i started debugging with him and had him sent me the log of the phone and he is getting a `XmlPullParserError` when he makes a call to the server

```
E/Message Exchange::CallWebService(6426): Exception: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT �������`I�...@1:18 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406c8808) 05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426): org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unterminated entity ref (position:TEXT �������`I�...@1:18 in java.io.InputStreamReader@406c8808) 05-31-12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.exception(KXmlParser.java:273)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.error(KXmlParser.java:269)05-31-12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushEntity(KXmlParser.java:781)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.pushText(KXmlParser.java:849)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextImpl(KXmlParser.java:354)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:1378)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:1408)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:100)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:195)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at ecm2.android.MessageExchange$1.run(MessageExchange.java:96)05-31 12:33:25.573 
W/System.err(6426):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)05-31 12:33:27.928
```

this is the line it always fails at

```
trans.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
```

that makes the call to the server and it just throws an error. I have the `same exact phone` this person has and I had him running the `exact version I am running`, I had not problems calling the server but he still had a problem.

I had him uninstall and reinstall several times so I dont know what would cause this on his phone and not mine?

this is how i create the XML

```
private static String CreateCallXML(String sDeviceID, String sEMailAddress, String sVersion) {
    Logging logger = new Logging();
    XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
    StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    try {
        serializer.setOutput(writer);
        serializer.startDocument("UTF-8", true);
        serializer.startTag("", "PostData");
        serializer.startTag("", "RetrieveMsg");
        serializer.attribute("", "ver", sVersion);
        serializer.attribute("", "DevID", sDeviceID);
        serializer.attribute("", "eMailAddress", sEMailAddress);
        logger.append("D", className, "CreateCallXML", "LastIncMsgID:" + Settings.LastIncMsgID);
        logger.append("D", className, "CreateCallXML", "LastDLMsgID: " + Settings.LastDLMsgID);
        serializer.attribute("", "LastIncMsgID", "" + Settings.LastIncMsgID);
        serializer.attribute("", "LastDLMsgID", "" + Settings.LastDLMsgID);
        serializer.endTag("", "RetrieveMsg");
        serializer.endTag("", "PostData");
        serializer.endDocument();
        return writer.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Update 2:**

after going through the code it appears that the users email address is the problem an example of the users email address is `abcd3961@gmail.com` if I use that it throws the exception when it hits the line to make the call to the server. If I change one letter in the email address it executes the call fine.

is this a ksoap problem? and how can I get around this as i cannot tell him to change his email address?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Unterminated entity** this error occurs when

1... Error in response string may be some entity are not closed.

```
<root>
    <a> first </a>
    <b>second             <----- </b> missing here
</roor>
```

2... You are getting some xml character in xml file

```
 like      & { } � ...
```

you need to replace all **&** with **& amp;** [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000095/1289716)

```
...
String str = writer.toString();
str = str.replaceAll("&","&amp;");
str = str.replaceAll("?","&#63;");
return str;
```

Comment: but why would this happen only on his phone and not mine? we both have the same phone running the same version and I have no problems

Comment: This problem not related to device but its about parsing.
I think there is some other error. Try this at once may be u get solution.

Comment: sorry I found what the real problem is, its the users email address for example `abcd3961@gmail.com` thats not the actual one but the numbers are the same just letters are different. anyway If i hard code that in my code I can reproduce the problem. If I change the any number/letter in his email address it executed the call fine but its just the exact `abcd3961@gmail.com` combination that is the problem. I have no idea why that would be a problem. I updated my question

Comment: Nice! Got me to the problem .. the service has a bad formed XML with a & that is not escaped

Answer (score 4):

I was having the same problem on an Android 2.2 device and found that ksoap2 2.6.5 isn't compatible with Android 2.2. Well I think that's the problem, all I know is it throws these errors. I downgraded my ksoap2 to 2.4 and it started working again.

Comment: yes 2.6.5 is not compatible but that was not the problem in my case, it was a server problem

Comment: For what it's worth, I fixed a similar problem by switching from 2.6.5 to 3.0 RC 4.  Previously it was triggering the unterminated entity ref exception on a 2.2 device but upgrading the library fixed it.

Comment: @DanDyer : Thanks a lot for the suggestion sir! You have no idea how freaked out I was when my app stopped working on 2.1 devices due to the compatibility error! Thanks a tonne!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. the solution was when I send the response from the XML I have to replace the "&" with & in the username, for that some users had the problem but others no.

So step 2 in "MAC" answer