# When parsing xml the character in String " 's " can not be parsed

Tags: android, string, character-encoding

This is my Code....I replaced the String like title.replace("’s", "is") but this can't work fo r me..

```
 NodeList Mymessage = fstElement.getElementsByTagName("title");
                     Element messageelement = (Element)Mymessage.item(0);
                     if(messageelement.hasChildNodes())
                     {
                         String title = ((Node)messageelement).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                         String title1=title.replace("’s", "is");
                         bin.setTitle(title1);
                         Log.v("titlr",title1);
                     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10000095/1289716

Comment: Before taking it as xml document; retrieve it in string form inputstream, then replace "'s" in that string. Then you can take it as xml document.

Comment: If you're getting an exception please post the stack trace

Comment: @Jules actual the string is broken when parsing the string like That's a Big Event!...only "That" is displayed in my log cat..

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `getNodeValue()` on the child node, use `getTextContent()` on the parent:

```
Element messageelement = (Element)Mymessage.item(0);
String title1=messageelement.getTextContent().replace("’s", "is");
if (title1.length() > 0) {
    bin.setTitle(title1);
    Log.v("titlr",title1);
}
```

Comment: What's the complete class name you're using?  I assumed it was a w3c.dom.Element, which inherits from w3c.dom.Node, which has the method as described at http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()