# Android Sqlite Special characters

Tags: java, android, regex, sqlite, special-characters

I have created an sqlite database and imported data from csv as UTF-8. It shows some unknown characters like `�`. In my android code i have managed this with regular expressions. Now I have problem with `\n`. My regular expression not detecting `\n` and it will replace `\` and `n` will be there.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9$' '-:|,&.\"\"()\n]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(descriptionfromDb);
String description = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

I have also tried using android `Html.fromHtml` and `Spannable` and both are not escaping the `�` symbol and `\n` not get converted to new line.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
description = description.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "");
```

For special characters see this answer:
[How to define special characters in array implementing java Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10000095/1289716)

Code for **Question mark** is `&#63;`

Comment: thanks for your help .But it seems not working for me. &#63 is code for question mark. But the symbol i have posted is not a question mark i think .Its an unknown character